# NSMutableArray with NSDate entries get days count

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdate

I have NSMutableArray with NSDates some dates are from a same day. What is the best way to get the number of NSDates for a particular day?

Edit:

Sorry, I am not fully explained. I need some kind of logic for getting number of dates for a particular day from the source array. So I loop through array, find exact date and I need to know How much days in the array for the same day.

Comment: A loop. What have you tried? What didn't work as you expected / hoped?

Comment: Check pls corrected message

Comment: What @Wain said -- loop through the array and count.  You do, of course, first need to define what you mean by "the same day".  You may find it easiest if the array is sorted (if that suits your other needs for the array).

Comment: I don't know what to tell to those who don't have a single line of code to initiate with when a question is specific.

Comment: Oh, I now understand what he wants.  That would be easy.  Geez, nobody knows what kind of objects the array contains, though.

Comment: Check pls the message again: I have NSMutableArray with NSDates ?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

```
NSDate *sourceDate = theDateThatYouAreLookingFor;
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
[calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:sourceDate];    

NSInteger day = [dateComponents day];
NSInteger month = [dateComponents month];
NSInteger year = [dateComponents year];

int count = 0;
//add check for existing dates on the same day
for(NSDate *checkDate in datesArray)
{
    dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:checkDate];    

    NSInteger checkDay = [dateComponents day];
    NSInteger checkMonth = [dateComponents month];
    NSInteger checkYear = [dateComponents year];

    if(checkDay == day && checkMonth == month && checkYear == year)
        count++;

}
//do something with count
```

**END EDIT**

The easiest way would be to iterate through the array and compare the day of each date as strings using an NSDateFormatter. Keep in mind that NSDateFormatters are expensive so you dont want to execute the process too often.

You can do something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dateInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];


NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyyMMdd";

for(NSDate *date in datesArray)
{
    NSString *dateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSNumber *currentCount = [dateInfo objectForKey:dateStr];
    if(currentCount)
    {
        //bump value
        [dateInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currentCount.intValue + 1] forKey:dateStr];
    }
    else
    {
        [dateInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:dateStr];
    }
}
```

Comment: Utterly unnecessary. This is what NSDateComponents is for.

Comment: I just did it this way to have a nice tag for the dictionary. I will edit my answer to show using date components too.

Comment: Edited again to respond better to edits in question

Comment: Thanks, I used solution with tags, testing this :)

Answer (score 1):

For performance reasons I would create two dates, "today" (00:00:00) and "tomorrow" (00:00:00). You use these dates as boundaries for you comparison. If a date is equal or greater than today and less than tomorrow it is a match.

Since a NSDate comparison is basically a double (the primitive type) comparison this method will be faster than comparing NSString objects or NSDateComponents. To create NSDateComponents a lot of math is used, and NSDateFormatters probably use NSDateComponents themselves.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *todayComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
todayComponents.year = 2013;
todayComponents.month = 6;
todayComponents.day = 21;

// today must be at the beginning of your search day. i.e. 00:00:00
NSDate *today = [calendar dateFromComponents:todayComponents]; 

NSDateComponents *oneDayOffset = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
oneDayOffset.day = 1;
NSDate *tomorrow = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDayOffset toDate:today options:0];

NSIndexSet *todaysIndexes = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([(NSDate *)obj compare:today] != NSOrderedAscending && [(NSDate *)obj compare:tomorrow] == NSOrderedAscending) {
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ obj is not earlier than "today" (= same time or later)
//                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ obj is earlier than "tomorrow"            
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}];

NSLog(@"%d", [todaysIndexes count]);
```

Replace today with your search date (at midnight) and you are ready to go.

Comment: Good solution. The only thing is that it will not include any dates that are on the same calendar date but earlier in the day. You would need to get NSDate for today at midnight and use then tomorrow at midnight and check to make sure the date is between. I believe that is what you are telling him to do, but the code doesn't quite accomplish it.

Comment: The code does exactly that.

Comment: Yes, but only if you set the dateComponents with components that you extract from the date you are searching for.

Comment: Yep, I've used this general scheme several times.  There are a number of ways to handle setting the midnight offset, and if you aren't worried about leap days you can keep advancing to the next day by adding 24 hours in seconds to the NSDate.